# Best practices for designing and maintaining Global classes?

Tags: managed-package, class, bestpractice, global-methods

We've always been conservative when it comes to exposing Globals for use by extension packages or subscriber extensions, and perhaps too conservative. We're considering being more proactive wth our global architecture, and we're discussing several changes to our current practice, in order to create a new set of best practices.

Topics we're discussing include "microglobals" that all share a common interface, minimizing the call tree, and when and how much we should use the internal API versioning that Salesforce provides.

Do you already have a set of best practices for designing and maintaining globals that works well for your packages and that you could share?

Comment: Though I can see this being somewhat opinion based I would think this can be turned into a useful Q&A with a little work, so voting to leave open.

Comment: Thank you, @DaveHumm. While a great number of practitioners use extension packages to provide additional functionality and modularity, Salesforce only discusses extensions as a way to support multiple editions. As a result, there is no guidance in the Salesforce documentation that covers real-life practice.

Comment: Note that Salesforce is planning to make significant changes to the packaging process over the next several releases, so that may change best practices over time. [This DF16 presentation](https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9#/session/a2q3A000000sWWJQA2) should give some more insight if you haven't seen it. I believe they are planning to allow you to develop extension packages in the same org as your main package, which should remove the necessity to make classes and methods global solely for extension packages (safe harbor, of course).

Comment: Honestly, @RobertWatson, the pkg 2.0 changes will call for even more discipline in our practice, since we'd be able to share publics between artifacts. Brrrr.

Comment: Here are some practice notes from another thread. 
* Prefer API-first, even if it means more globals. 
* Prefer use of interfaces and class extensions. 
* Prefer static stateless methods on services with the use of DTOs.
* Establish an API Review process. 
* Enforce strict naming conventions, especially on API elements. 
* Prefer Invocable Methods as an API strategy. 
* Avoid the Salesforce behavior versioning.
* Prefer versioning through introduction of a successor class (Global2, Global3). 
* Consider injecting @deprecated when deploying to packaging orgs.

Comment: for webservices where we are writing both sides of the call, we've gone to receiving one string parameter and returning one string. The actual parameter list can be deserialized from the passed string. This lets us alter parameter lists (since we're writing both sides of the call) without having to re-create the class again and again

Comment: Considering the suggestion: "Prefer Invocable Methods as an API strategy" That means you would value Flow over Lightning Components and Aura Enabled methods. If you are doing globals for your own package extensions, it's better to be judicious in the use of invocables.

Comment: However, If you are doing globals to give sys admins access to code, then make sure you've got great documentation first. And since only one method per class can be invocable, preferring the annotation is going to create a lot of noise for sys admins in the orgs with your package, and not everyone needs that, to be honest.  I think it would be far better to let folks create their own invocables from your globals.

Comment: And you can't remove invocables from a managed package, so you can never get rid of all that noise you created if you prefer them.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an attempt at answering holistically but to share my current best practices. I want to update this answer if things change.

As of Winter20 unlocked packages are not yet available for ISVs. Even with shared namespace, `@namespaceaccessible`, ..., access got restricted again. More [methods/classes need to be global](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_apex_same_package.htm) due to security concerns if they live in different packages.

On the up-side, providing Field Level Security is much less of an headache with new features like [`WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED`](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_apex_WithSecurityEnforced_GA.htm) for SOQL becoming GA with Spring20.

There are currently two best practices I think fit everyone:

- always add (empty) constructors to global classes

  The engine will always add one if there is none present and should you decide to release your own constructor in the future, package upgrade will fail because the hidden global constructor is attempted to be overwritten.
- make method arguments generic: `myGlobalMethod(Map<String,Object> params) {}`

  This give you the flexibility to change implementation details after initial release.